# ILnumerics trial license error when try to start on another machine

Tags: ilnumerics

Is it possible to distribute application with ILNumerics interpolation module reference while it is trial? According to current trial License i can distribute for about two weeks to show functionality on another machine(customer). But im getting error such as "the type initializer ILNumerics.Toolboxes.Interpolation threw an exception". I do not install ILNumerics on another machine. Just try to execute my application with all needed ILNumerics dlls.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is possible. My problem was in references. I have more than 10 projects in solution.